# Decode string using python || SHA256

Tags: python-3.x, md5, sha256, hashlib

I am currently using **hashlib** library in python to encrypt a URL using SHA256. Following is the code.

```
import hashlib
url='https://booking.com'
hs = hashlib.sha256(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(hs) # 037c89f2570ac1cff92d67643f570bec93ebea7f0222e105616590a9673be21f
```

Now, I want to decrypt and get back the url. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: SHA256 is not encryption, it’s a hash. Hashes are one-way, you can’t go backwards

Comment: @Sami, are there any two-way hashes?

Comment: No, hashes are by definition one-way

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, Then I better use some encryption algorithms like AES? Am I right?

Comment: If you want to go back then yes, you need an encryption algorithm instead

Comment: BTW, if you manage to "decrypt" this hash without any information about the input and without brute-force, you'll probably win some prize from the NSA

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests something that is by-definition impossible, and thus fails the *answerable* portion of Stack Overflow's topicality criterion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't do that with a hash**

**You should use a Cipher for example the [AES Cipher](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/)**

---

Example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def resize_length(string):
    #resizes the String to a size divisible by 16 (needed for this Cipher)
    return string.rjust((len(string) // 16 + 1) * 16)

def encrypt(url, cipher):
    # Converts the string to bytes and encodes them with your Cipher
    return cipher.encrypt(resize_length(url).encode())

def decrypt(text, cipher):
    # Converts the string to bytes and decodes them with your Cipher
    return cipher.decrypt(text).decode().lstrip()


# It is important to use 2 ciphers with the same information, else the system breaks (at least for me)
# Define the Cipher with your data (Encryption Key and IV)
cipher1 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
cipher2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
decrypt(encrypt("https://booking.com", cipher1), cipher2)
```

This should return *https://booking.com*.

**Edit:**
If you want to have an encoded string in the hex format you could use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) command in combination.

For exmple:

```
#For encoding
cipherstring = cipher.encrypt(resize_length(url).encode())
cipherstring = "".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in cipherstring)

#For decoding
text = bytes.fromhex(text)
original_url = cipher.decrypt(text).decode().lstrip()
```

> The
>   "".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in cipherstring)
>   means every character gets encoded in hexadecimal format and the list of characters gets joined with the seperator "" (it is beeing converted to a string)

Comment: encrypt("https://booking.com", cipher1) gives some weird very long string with lots of back-slashes, is there a way to convert into a hexadecimal string?

Comment: Wow, Amazing! Thanks a lot, @Kumpelinus.